# Retrieve plaintext WS-Security password at service endpoint with Metro + WSIT?

Tags: java, jax-ws, ws-security, java-metro-framework, wsit

I'm writing a SOAP service (let's call it X) that acts as a "forwarding proxy" of sorts, replacing several elements in the body, then calling another SOAP service (Y).  I would like to use the same WS-Security credentials (**plaintext** username and password) that I receive in X when I call Y, but I am having trouble retrieving the value of the Password element.

The policy that I declare in my `wsit-package.service.xml` file references an implementation of `com.sun.xml.wss.impl.callback.PasswordValidationCallback.PasswordValidator`:

```
<wsp1_2:Policy wsu:Id="UsernameToken" 
  xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
  xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702"
  xmlns:wsss="http://schemas.sun.com/2006/03/wss/server"
  xmlns:wspp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/wsit/policy">
  <wsp1_2:ExactlyOne>
    <wsp1_2:All>
      <sp:SupportingTokens>
        <wsp1_2:Policy>
          <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/
ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient" />
          <sp:IncludeTimestamp />
        </wsp1_2:Policy>
      </sp:SupportingTokens>
      <wsss:ValidatorConfiguration wspp:visibility="private" >
        <wsss:Validator name="usernameValidator" 
            classname="com.service.validator.SecurityValidator" />
      </wsss:ValidatorConfiguration>
    </wsp1_2:All>
  </wsp1_2:ExactlyOne>
</wsp1_2:Policy>
```

I am able to access the password in the validator:

```
@Override
public boolean validate(Request request) throws PasswordValidationException {
    String password = ((PlainTextPasswordRequest) request).getPassword();
    return true;
}
```

However, since the validator does not have access to the WebServiceContext, there is not a convenient place to store it that is accessible to my service endpoint.

With other headers, e.g. WS-Addressing, I am able to use a Handler (implementation of `SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>`) to pull out the values, then put them back in the context under the application scope for my endpoint to retrieve.  WS-Security headers are already stripped by the time the SOAP message gets to my handler chain, so there is no way to retrieve their values in a Handler.

**Short of doing something drastic like using the validator to store the password in a database/global map/threadlocal storage, is there any way for me to retrieve the WS-Security Password that was supplied at my endpoint?**

I should note that I am able to access the WS-Security Username information at my endpoint via `Subject subj = SubjectAccessor.getRequesterSubject(context)`, but this does not appear to contain the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lack of a better solution, I ended up using ThreadLocal storage to access the WS-Security Username and Password in my service endpoint:

```
package com.my.ws.validator;

import com.sun.xml.wss.impl.callback.PasswordValidationCallback.PasswordValidationException;
import com.sun.xml.wss.impl.callback.PasswordValidationCallback.PasswordValidator;
import com.sun.xml.wss.impl.callback.PasswordValidationCallback.PlainTextPasswordRequest;
import com.sun.xml.wss.impl.callback.PasswordValidationCallback.Request;

public class SecurityValidator implements PasswordValidator {

    private static final ThreadLocal<String> username = new ThreadLocal<String>();
    private static final ThreadLocal<String> password = new ThreadLocal<String>();

    @Override
    public boolean validate(final Request request) throws PasswordValidationException {

        if (request instanceof PlainTextPasswordRequest) {
            PlainTextPasswordRequest plainText = (PlainTextPasswordRequest) request;

            if (null == plainText.getUsername() || plainText.getUsername().trim().isEmpty())
                throw new PasswordValidationException("A username must be provided");
            else
                username.set(plainText.getUsername());

            if (null == plainText.getPassword() || plainText.getPassword().trim().isEmpty())
                throw new PasswordValidationException("A password must be provided");
            else
                password.set(plainText.getPassword());

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static String getUsername() {
        String user = username.get();
        username.remove();
        return user;
    }

    public static String getPassword() {
        String pass = password.get();
        password.remove();
        return pass;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's clever but seems to be a bit hacky. How do you know that for each request under every circumstance the password validator and the ws implementation will be executed from the same thread?